# pghero relying on old postgres package

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13, pghero

I am trying to install [pghero](https://github.com/ankane/pghero) and came across a package that doesn't exist in the pgdg repo anymore:

```
# yum install pghero
Last metadata expiration check: 0:08:39 ago on Wed 19 Apr 2023 03:09:19 PM UTC.
Error: 
 Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - nothing provides postgresql93 needed by pghero-3.3.3-1681837339.61a986e6.sles12.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

`--nobest` still won't let me download, just says that it's necessary for the previous versions as well.

`--skip-broken` doesn't install anything.

I checked the pgdg repo and saw that it only contains postgresql11 and up.

How can I get around this, or is there another way to install pghero?